# Why isn't the word transcription used in the off-topics list?

Tags: discussion, transcription

After reviewing some of the meta discussion about what analysis questions are on-topic it seems clear the real issue is about transcription. Questions/requests for transcription or requiring transcription are off-topic.

So why isn't the word *transcription* actually used in pages like: 
https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Something like:

- "don't ask questions which require transcription by ear."
- "questions about analysis from a score or lead sheet are welcome."

It would make the guideline much easier to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there between the lines in the on-topic page between these two bullet points:

> - identifying a song, style/genre, instrument/equipment, technique,    chord progression, etc.
> - identifying notes/chords/meters in your favourite song

It's not the clearest, but it is there. After a review of the history of the on-topic page it was there until we made analysis on topic. It's a good point that transcription should be mentioned by name, so I've slightly tweaked what we have in the second bullet point to:

> transcription of specific works including identifying
>   notes/chords/meters in your favourite song

We don't have control over the don't ask page it is an SE standard as you can see it the exact same on [other sites.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) It's just talking about the general SE policy across all SE sites. It's pretty flexible how it's applied from site to site and the on-topic section is much more important.

This was not the first time this [discussion was brought up.](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2140/7222) Ever since analysis was allowed it's been pointed out we don't do transcription.

Comment: Thanks for changing the on-topic page. I didn't know the "don't ask" page was un-editable.