# Which questions/answers would most benefit from music markup like ABC?

Tags: discussion, music-notation

The conclusion of [Should we agree on requesting ABC music markup now, unequivocally?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2460/28) seems to be a resounding Yes.  As such, I would like to present our case to SE and see if we can get this done.  And for that, I want to demonstrate more than just that we want it — I want to show that we **need** it.

So, which posts would gain the biggest benefit from this?  Which posts make it clear that something is lacking in this area?  Please include your rationale for each post.

---

**I have submitted a request to SE.  Now we wait.**

Link to the ABC.js project: https://github.com/paulrosen/abcjs

And see [How could ABC notation be embedded in our posts' Markdown?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2507/28)

---

List of all related discussions: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2460?sort=newest

Comment: Could you add a link to the library and an example of what the markup would look like in the context of Markdown? Is there a particular delimiter that would make sense? (`$` is often a good choice.) Are there any dependencies that this would drag in? Basically, can you help make it easier for a developer to investigate?

Comment: @JonEricson Added a link.  It relies on [Raphael](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) (which it seems to package with itself anyways) and jQuery.  I'll ask someone more familiar with it to address the question about Markdown.

Comment: @JonEricson Good examples of markup at http://abcnotation.com/examples.  The $ delimiter would work as it is not a special character.  The list of special characters in ABC can be found at http://abcnotation.com/wiki/abc:standard:v2.1#text_strings   I am also a web developer so technical questions can be directed to me and I'd be happy to beta-test.

Comment: @JonEricson I posted something on delimiters [in another question](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/how-could-abc-notation-be-embedded-in-our-posts-markdown/2508#2508). Tl;dr: I'd advocate using `$$ ... $$`.

Answer (score 11):

Here's just a short list of what I found searching the site for 20 minutes. Most of the examples, people had to take a screen shot of what they were explaining or just put the note letters instead of visualizing the music.

- https://music.stackexchange.com/a/1166
- https://music.stackexchange.com/a/40222
- https://music.stackexchange.com/a/22242
- https://music.stackexchange.com/a/16999
- https://music.stackexchange.com/a/33950
- https://music.stackexchange.com/a/14783
- https://music.stackexchange.com/a/583
- https://music.stackexchange.com/a/23977
- https://music.stackexchange.com/a/4945
- https://music.stackexchange.com/a/6919
- [Pentatonic scale with a sharpened 2nd note, any name?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/17632/7222)
- https://music.stackexchange.com/a/12074
- [Flat symbol in key signature and bar](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/24355/7222)
- [Playing arpeggio on black notes with white note third](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43428/playing-arpeggio-on-black-notes-with-white-note-third)
- [What would be the proper fingering for these 2 small parts?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32787)
- [How to correctly invert non-compound greater-than-octave intervals?](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/43544/72220)
- [Swing feel - are triplets and 8th note notations rhythmically the same?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/44394/swing-feel-are-triplets-and-8th-note-notations-rhythmically-the-same)

And from the first page of questions :

- [A-minor scale has different notes when descending](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43355/a-minor-scale-has-different-notes-when-descending)
- [Which scales are used by Tom Morello?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16992/which-scales-are-used-by-tom-morello)
- [Why do the notes of Melodic-Minor Scale change when you play it in descending order?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43363/why-do-the-notes-of-melodic-minor-scale-change-when-you-play-it-in-descending-or)

There were another 3 on the first page that might have benefited from being able to write notation, but these were the clearest cases.

Comment: Feel free to add more examples.

Comment: This one has embedded jpgs that could have easily been done in abc:
http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/41642

Comment: And (without in any way criticising the comprehensive answer given by Caleb Hines to http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43929 parts of that answer could have been expressed in abc rather than words

Answer (score 6):

We specifically allow analysis questions, but require (or at least *strongly encourage*) such questions to include a score of the section under question. See, for example, Dom's answer here: [Criteria for allowed analysis of specific music](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/854/criteria-for-allowed-analysis-of-specific-music).

In this case, analysis questions would benefit hugely from the ability to textually specify notation directly.

Answer (score 5):

ABC notation is particularly useful when describing chord choices and substitutions with regard to melody or when describing note choices as they relate to chords.

For example, in my answers the OP would have benefited significantly from ABC in the following answers:

- [Determining Key / Key Change / Chords?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22546/determining-key-key-change-chords/22557#22557)
- [Is there a minimum of notes and chords i need to determine the key of a song?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/is-there-a-minimum-of-notes-and-chords-i-need-to-determine-the-key-of-a-song/22122#22122)
- [Is there any theory to decide a set of plausible chords per measure where a whole melody of a song is given?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17067/is-there-any-theory-to-decide-a-set-of-plausible-chords-per-measure-where-a-whol/17704#17704)
- [Application of different fingering pattern exercises to improvisation on the guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/30632/application-of-different-fingering-pattern-exercises-to-improvisation-on-the-gui/31007#31007)

and then questions like this would benefit from ABC as a matter of course:
 - [How to write music using standard notation / Finding key](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20479/how-to-write-music-using-standard-notation-finding-key)

Answer (score 4):

I would be happy to explain specific [practicing exercises](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/34027/8761) with notations. It's a little clunky using words but can be easy to remember and execute when seen as notation.

Questions asking for detailed execution descriptions such as a [position](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/37566/8761) [changes](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4873/downshifting-in-high-positions-on-violin) need to express which finger is where on the fingerboard, and notation convey this expression in a faster and clearer way.